# How to create a postgres connection that uses context manager?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I was trying to create a wrapper class that used **enter**/**exit** to allow for a context manager to close a postgres db connection.

```
class ClosingConnection:
def __init__(self, schema_name: str) -> None:
    """
    :param schema_name: the db schema (i.e. the tenant)
    """
    super().__init__()
    self.schema_name = schema_name

def __enter__(self):
    try:
        self.conn = psycopg2.connect(
                host=os.environ["DB_HOST"],
                port=os.environ["DB_PORT"],
                database=os.environ["DB_NAME"],
                user=os.environ["DB_USERNAME"],
                password=password,  
                options=f"-c search_path={self.schema_name}",
                cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor,
        )
        return self.conn
    except psycopg2.OperationalError:
        pass

def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
    self.conn.close()
```

Usage

```
def get_db(schema_name: str):
    return ClosingConnection(schema_name)

with get_db("test") as db:
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("some sql")
    rv = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
```

This works fine to retrieve data, but if I do an upsert, only the first upsert is performed.  The remaining ones rv returns correctly, but the actual database is never updated.

In contrast if I get rid of the closing class, this works fine

Usage

```
def get_db(schema_name: str):
    try:
        self.conn = psycopg2.connect(
                host=os.environ["DB_HOST"],
                port=os.environ["DB_PORT"],
                database=os.environ["DB_NAME"],
                user=os.environ["DB_USERNAME"],
                password=password,  
                options=f"-c search_path={self.schema_name}",
                cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor,
        )
        return self.conn
    except psycopg2.OperationalError:
        pass

conn = get_db("test") 
try:      
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("some sql")
    rv = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
finally:
    conn.close()
```

For curiosity here is the upsert command I'm using (I've also tried the older with upsert version)

```
INSERT INTO settings_account (setting_name, setting_value)
    VALUES (%(setting_name)s, %(setting_value)s)
    ON CONFLICT (setting_name)
    DO
        UPDATE SET setting_value=EXCLUDED.setting_value
    RETURNING *
```

Why is the wrapper class causing the db writes to fail?  Is the idea of wrapper class flawed?

Comment: Where do you call `commit()`?

Comment: I don't. is that something I need to call for the class case?

Comment: oh I guess the commit is handled as part of the original db cxt manager

Answer (score 2):

Thanks the comment above, i was able to get this working with:

```
    class ClosingConnection:
def __init__(self, schema_name: str) -> None:
    """
    :param schema_name: the db schema (i.e. the tenant)
    """
    super().__init__()
    self.schema_name = schema_name

def __enter__(self):
    try:
        self.conn = psycopg2.connect(
                host=os.environ["DB_HOST"],
                port=os.environ["DB_PORT"],
                database=os.environ["DB_NAME"],
                user=os.environ["DB_USERNAME"],
                password=password,  
                options=f"-c search_path={self.schema_name}",
                cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor,
        )
        return self.conn
    except psycopg2.OperationalError:
        pass

def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
    self.conn.commit()
    self.conn.close()

def get_db(schema_name: str):
    return ClosingConnection(schema_name)

with get_db("test") as db:
    with db.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("some sql")
        rv = cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: Sorry--was deep into work after I left my comment.  In psycopg2, the `cursor` objects have a context manager built in that issues a commit on `__exit__()` so long as no errors were encountered.  My suggestion would be to take the `commit()` out of your `ClosingConnection` and do a nested `with db.cursor() as cursor:` block inside your `with get_db("test") as db:`  Please don't take this the wrong way, but if you are going to be fastidious to this level about these things, then you may as well go all the way :-)

Comment: I believe the ```commit()``` is in the connection ```__exit__``` instead of the  cursor context manager.

From the docs:
https://www.psycopg.org/docs/connection.html

"Connections can be used as context managers. Note that a context wraps a transaction: if the context exits with success the transaction is committed, if it exits with an exception the transaction is rolled back. Note that the connection is not closed by the context and it can be used for several contexts."

Comment: I tried it anyways, but adding a ```with db.cursor() as cursor:``` doesn't perform the commit()

Comment: It does for me.  Here is the relevant passage in the docs:  "When a connection exits the with block, if no exception has been raised by the block, the transaction is committed. In case of exception the transaction is rolled back."  https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html

Comment: yes, the docs say "When a connection exits the with block....the transaction is committed".  This is saying the connection ```with``` block not the cursor ```with``` block.  The closing class code above doesn't use a ```with``` block for the connection, therefore the commit needs to be called explicitly

Comment: You are right, and I am wrong.  The bottom line is to use the built-in `with` block in psycopg2.